# Call PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec from the UI thread

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, swt

I've seen:

```
if (Display.getCurrent() == null){
   PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay.asyncExec(aRunnable)
} else {
   aRunnable.run();
}
```

I wonder if it's really required to manually check the current execution thread. If I unconditionally use

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay.asyncExec(aRunnable)
```

won't the Display implementation handle both cases correctly anyways? And if so, will it also handle it correctly when replacing `asyncExec` with `syncExec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an implementation detail how `syncExec` or `asyncExec` operate when called from the UI thread.  The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html) states:

> Causes the run() method of the runnable to be invoked by the user-interface thread at the next reasonable opportunity.

This means that your `Runnable` could simply be put in the queue and executed at the next dispatch loop, potentially behind other `Runnable`s.  If you specifically invoke the `run` method of your `Runnable` when on the UI thread, then you have more control over its scheduling.

Certainly, the behavior of `syncExec` and `asyncExec` may differ when being called from the UI thread.  I seem to recall that `syncExec` will execute immediately when called from the UI thread and that `asyncExec` will always queue its work, but again, this is an implementation detail and is not guaranteed.

Further, **no**, you cannot replace every instance of `asyncExec` with an instance of `syncExec`.  `syncExec` will wait for the runnable in question to be posted and executed by the UI thread, which can pose serious contention problems.  Imagine this code running on a non-UI thread:

```
synchronized(foo)
{
    display.asynExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized(foo)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello!");
            }
        }
     });
}
```

This is a trivial example - but it will not deadlock.  The `asyncExec` call will queue this runnable and return, which will drop out of the `synchronized` block so that the runnable on the UI thread can later obtain the lock.  However, replacing this with `syncExec` will surely deadlock.

In general, it is advisable to use `asyncExec` unless you believe you need the execution guarantees that `syncExec` makes.

Comment: I think you can remove the sections starting from "Further, no..", which is irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 1):

SWT's Display will handle `syncExec` and `asyncExec` correctly regardless they are called from the UI thread or another thread.

Making such a check makes sense if you **really** want to avoid the tiny overhead of calling those APIs and prefer synchronous execution as on the posted code.